# Find the number of times that each row of a matrix appears in another

Tags: r, matrix

We have two matrices, which we denote by A and B respectively. The aim is to find the number of times that each row of A appears in B, memorizing these numbers in a vector x whose i-th element corresponds to the i-th row of A. For example:

```
# A=
1 2 3
1 1 1
2 0 1
1 4 5

# B=
2 0 1
0 0 1
0 0 2
```

Then the vector x is:

```
0 0 1 0
```

because the rows

```
1 2 3, 1 1 1, 1 4 5
```

appear 0 times in B, while the row

```
2 0 1
```

appears 1 time in B.

The following is my solution:

```
m3 <- rbind(A, B)
count(m3)
```

which returns:

```
  x.1 x.2 x.3 freq
1   0   0   1    1
2   1   0   2    1
3   1   1   1    1
4   1   2   3    1
5   1   4   5    1
6   2   0   1    2
```

This is not the desidered result. The correct one takes into account the original order of A (while the order of remaining row of B does not matter); in our example:

```
1   1   2   3    1
2   1   1   1    1
3   2   0   1    2
4   1   4   5    1
1   0   0   1    1
2   1   0   2    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short version:

```
x <- vector()
for(i in 1:nrow(A)) x[i] = sum(colSums(!t(B) - A[i,] == 0) == 0)
```

Or you can make it cleaner subbing `apply` for the `for` loop. Answer,

```
> x
[1] 0 0 1 0
```

Here's the `apply` version:

```
x <- sapply(1:nrow(A), function(x) sum(colSums(!t(B) - A[x,] == 0) == 0) )
```

I'm sure it can be simplified further.

Comment: Thank you! How could I substitute `apply` for the `for` loop?

Comment: Updated answer to give you an apply version

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `dplyr`. `m_final` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)
dt <- rbind(A, B) %>%
  as_data_frame() 

dt_unique <- dt %>%
  distinct()

dt_count <- dt %>%
  group_by_all() %>%
  count()

m_final <- dt_unique %>%
  left_join(dt_count) %>%
  as.matrix()

m_final
#      V1 V2 V3 n
# [1,]  1  2  3 1
# [2,]  1  1  1 1
# [3,]  2  0  1 2
# [4,]  1  4  5 1
# [5,]  0  0  1 1
# [6,]  0  0  2 1
```

**DATA**

```
A <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3,
              1, 1, 1,
              2, 0, 1,
              1, 4, 5), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

B <- matrix(c(2, 0, 1,
              0, 0, 1,
              0, 0, 2), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

Comment: Isn't `dt <- rbind(A, B) %>% as_data_frame() %>% group_by_all() %>% count()` simpler? I'm not understanding the idea behind `dt_unique <- dt %>% distinct()` and subsequent `left_join`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The OP stated that the original order of rows is important, so I want to keep the order.

Comment: Ah, got it. That's important to notice.